# How to defer a remap until the affected keymap has been created?

Tags: key-bindings, hooks, keymap, isearch

I wanted to change the behavior of isearch in the minibuffer, making <kbd>Return</kbd> both accept a search result (`isearch-exit`) and submit it (`minibuffer-complete-and-exit`). This is the behavior I've grown to like with Ctrl-R in the shell.

```
(defun ivan/isearch-exit ()
  "Run isearch-exit, and if in the minibuffer, submit the search result as input."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-exit)
  (if (minibuffer-window-active-p (selected-window))
      (minibuffer-complete-and-exit)))
```

The first time `isearch-mode` is entered, it binds <kbd>Return</kbd> to `isearch-exit` in `overriding-terminal-local-map` (which takes precedence over all other keymaps). So I'm remapping `isearch-exit` to my custome `ivan/isearch-exit` in that keymap.

The problem is, I can't simply do the remapping in my init file, because `overriding-terminal-local-map` is nil at that point. To get around this, I've done the remapping in a hook:

```
(defun ivan/remap-isearch-exit ()
  (define-key
    overriding-terminal-local-map [remap isearch-exit] #'ivan/isearch-exit))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook #'ivan/remap-isearch-exit)
```

This works, *but* it means I'm doing the remapping *every* time isearch starts, which is unnecessary. Not that it hurts anything (except maybe performance?), but I'd like to avoid doing so. Now I've added a variable to make sure the remap only occurs the first time isearch is entered.

```
(setq ivan/remapped-isearch-exit nil)

(defun ivan/remap-isearch-exit ()
  (unless ivan/remapped-isearch-exit
    (setq ivan/remapped-isearch-exit t)
    (define-key
      overriding-terminal-local-map [remap isearch-exit] #'ivan/isearch-exit)))
```

But it makes me wonder if there's a better way. Is there something I could hook into that's run when `overriding-terminal-local-map` is first created? Or is there another approach altogether that I'm not aware of?

*Update*: Thanks to lawlist's answer, I now have the following:

```
(eval-after-load "isearch"
  '(define-key isearch-mode-map [remap isearch-exit] #'ivan/isearch-exit))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because certain components of `isearch.el` are autoloaded by default, Emacs recognizes the existence of the autoloaded functions when they are called during an Emacs session -- the entire library is loaded once an autoloaded function is called.  The following are two different approaches to changing the settings -- `. . .` means to add your own additional stuff as needed -- the first approach will be slightly faster than the second approach when starting Emacs:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "isearch" '(progn
  . . .))
```

or

```lisp
(require 'isearch)
. . .
```

Comment: This didn't work quite as expected, but it did lead me to solution. Emacs was still complaining about the keymap being nil, and I noticed this line in the definition of `isearch-mode-map`: `(setq overriding-terminal-local-map isearch-mode-map)`. So I tried the more obvious solution - remapping in `isearch-mode-map`. I thought I'd tried that already, but I must have tried `minibuffer-local-isearch-map` instead. Anyway, it works!